# Child entity links are not returned in ApiTestCase but work elsewhere

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, api-platform.com

I have two entities, a Client (accessors snipped)

```
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use ApiPlatform\Core\Annotation\ApiResource;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Annotation\Groups;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;

/**
 * @ApiResource(
 *     collectionOperations={
 *         "get"={"normalization_context"={"groups"="client:list"}},
 *         "post"
 *     },
 *     itemOperations={
 *         "get"={"normalization_context"={"groups"="client:item"}},
 *     },
 *     paginationEnabled=false,
 *     order={"name"="ASC"}
 * )
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\ClientRepository")
 */
class Client
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @Groups({"client:list", "client:item"})
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     * @Assert\NotBlank
     * @Groups({"client:list", "client:item"})
     */
    private $name;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\Package", mappedBy="client")
     * @Groups({"client:item"})
     */
    private $packages;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->packages = new ArrayCollection();
    }
```

And a Package:

```
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use ApiPlatform\Core\Annotation\ApiFilter;
use ApiPlatform\Core\Annotation\ApiResource;
use ApiPlatform\Core\Bridge\Doctrine\Orm\Filter\SearchFilter;
use DateTime;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Annotation\Groups;

/**
 * @ApiResource(
 *     collectionOperations={
 *         "get"={"normalization_context"={"groups"="package:list"}},
 *         "post"={"denormalization_context"={"groups"="package:list"}},
 *     },
 *     itemOperations={
 *         "get"={"normalization_context"={"groups"="package:item"}},
 *         "delete",
 *     },
 *
 * )
 * @ApiFilter(SearchFilter::class, properties={"client": "exact"})
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\PackageRepository")
 * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks()
 */
class Package
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @Groups({"package:list", "package:item"})
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     * @Groups({"package:list", "package:item"})
     */
    private $name;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="datetime")
     * @Groups({"package:item"})
     */
    private $createdAt;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\Client", inversedBy="packages")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
     * @Groups({"package:list", "package:item"})
     */
    private $client;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=64)
     */
    private $status;
```

When I view the API browser (or use cURL on the cli) and query for a single client, I can see the child package entities being returned in the response (requested as JSON only to make the payload clearer):

```
{
  "id": 1,
  "name": "First Client",
  "packages": [
    "/api/packages/1",
    "/api/packages/2"
  ]
}
```

However, in my test case the child entities are not being returned. My test looks as follows:

```
    public function testItShouldReturnASpecificClient(): void
    {
        $client = static::createClient();
        $response = $client->request('GET', '/api/clients/1', ['headers' => ['Accept' => 'application/json']]);
        $data = json_decode($response->getContent(), false);

        static::assertSame(1, $data->id);
        static::assertCount(2, $data->packages);
    }
```

And the second assertion fails. When I dump the response I can see that the packages property has not been populated:

```
class stdClass#1937 (3) {
  public $id =>
  int(1)
  public $name =>
  string(12) "First Client"
  public $packages =>
  array(0) {
  }
}
```

What am I missing here to make this behave as the API does outside of test?

Comment: Try changing `@ManyToOne(@ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\Package", mappedBy="client", fetch="EAGER")` for that annotation in the Client.

Comment: @beltouche That doesn't change my result in the test, and to be honest it seems like a weird fix if my entities behave as they should elsewhere. Thanks for the suggestion though.

Comment: It is possible that the test case has not populate and/or persist packages data for client 1.

Comment: @ihsan I have looked at both the fixtures (I use `hautelook/alice-bundle`) and the database and the relations are defined correctly. Indeed, they are the same fixutres that I have loaded in dev that work with no issues.

Comment: Try to get and dump the data in test case using model manager instead of calling the API. See if it different.

Comment: @ihsan thank you - I wasn't mapping both sides of the relationship in my fixtures which was preventing them from loading - do you want to write this up as an answer so that I can accept it?

Comment: @frak glad I could help. No I won't write an answer, but you can write and accept your own answer. Future fellow might get benefit.. Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with my fixtures all along, thanks to @ihsan for guiding me in my debugging.

I had previously assumed that all I needed to do was link to the client in a package:

```
App\Entity\Package:
  package_1:
    name: 'Inactive Package For First Client'
    createdAt: <dateTime('today -1 year')>
    status: 'INACTIVE'
    client: '@client_1'
  package_2:
    name: 'Active Package For First Client'
    createdAt: <dateTime('today -1 week')>
    status: 'ACTIVE'
    client: '@client_1'
```

However, for the tests to work correctly I had to also associate the packages to the client:

```
App\Entity\Client:
  client_1:
    name: First Client
    packages:
      - '@package_1'
      - '@package_2'
```